# Trying to get a loop to work through alternate arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, char

I'm trying to print out a string by alternating its letter cases. I want `YourString` to come out as `YoUrStRiNg`. I've tried three things but I can't get the loop to work the way I need it to. Here's what I have so far:

```java
//one attempt
String s = "yourString";
String x = "";

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 2) {
    for (int j = 1; j < s.length(); j += 2) {
        x += Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i));
        x += Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(j));
    }
}
System.out.println(x);
```

```java
//the desired result but not the ideal solution
String[] sArray = {"Your", "String"};
String f = "";
for (String n : sArray) {
    f += n;
}

char[] c = f.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
char[] d = f.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

System.out.print(c[0]);
System.out.print(d[1]);
System.out.print(c[2]);
System.out.print(d[3]);
System.out.print(c[4]);
System.out.print(d[5]);
System.out.print(c[6]);
System.out.print(d[7]);
System.out.print(c[8]);
System.out.print(d[9]);
System.out.println();
```

```java
//third attempt with loop but the first loop keeps starting from zero
String t = "";
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i += 2) {
    for (int j = 1; j < d.length; j += 2) {
        t += Character.toUpperCase(c[i]);
        t += Character.toLowerCase(d[j]);
    }
    System.out.print(t);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't want to spoil the complete answer as this is probably some programming assignment. So you should iterate the string only once and if a character is uppercase, you should make it lowercase and vice versa. A function like https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase(char) might be handy for that.

Comment: @Sebi The goal isn't to swap the existing case, it's to alternate based on position.

Comment: Without wanting to spoil the answer either, iterate over the string characters and, use something like 
`i % 2 == 0 ? Character.toUpperCase(text.charAt(i)) : Character.toLowerCase(text.charAt(i))` 
to decide what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's no need to iterate more than once through the elements of the String. As you need to change the case of the character alternatively, you can just count the position of your iteration, by using the operator `%`. So, for example, given `c` as the current String character, the operation would be like this:

```
System.out.print(i % 2 == 0, (char)Character.toUpperCase(c) : (char)Character.toLowerCase(c));
```

However, you can actually take advantages from Java Stream and lambda expression, so to realize a very elegant solution for that.
I am going to show you my proposal solution. The only issue is that you cannot actually have a proper cycle variable, as the variable you access inside the lamba expression must be final or effective final, so I used a sort of trick for it.
That is just to give you an idea, you can actually personalize, make it reusable, and improve it as you wish:

```
public class MyStringTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String s = "yourString";
      
      initializeCycleVariable();
      s.chars().forEach(c -> 
        {System.out.print( MyStringTest.getAndIncrement() %2 == 0 ? 
                           (char)Character.toUpperCase(c) : 
                           (char)Character.toLowerCase(c));
        });
    }
    
    private static int i = 0;
    
    public initializeCycleVariable() {  i = 0; }
    public static int getAndIncrement() { return i++; }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
YoUrStRiNg
```

Comment: Didn't know the modulus operand could be used for iterations, thanks.

Comment: @DazedandConfucius if you are happy with the answer, please accept and upvote, so it can help other developers in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over the string char by char. You could do upper case for the even indexes, and lower case for the odd ones. Sorry for not providing more detail, but it is clear that this is an assignment.

Comment: you could give an example atleast, for demonstrating what you wrote.

Comment: It's not an assignment, I'm not even enrolled in any summer courses. This is just one of many exercises I'm giving myself to improve my programming skills.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one out,

```
String s = "yourString", x = "";
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){

    if(i % 2 == 0)
        x += Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i));
    else
        x += Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i));
}
System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: I feel this snippet is easier.